# CoreOS docker pull flaky

Tags: docker, coreos

I've the following Unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Bootstrap Docker Swarm cluster
Requires=docker.service coreos-metadata.service
After=docker.service coreos-metadata.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
Environment="AWSCLI_IMAGE=quay.io/coreos/awscli:latest"
EnvironmentFile=/run/metadata/coreos
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/systemctl is-active docker.service
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker pull $AWSCLI_IMAGE
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker run --rm --net=host \
            -v /run/metadata:/run/metadata \
            -w /run/metadata \
            $AWSCLI_IMAGE aws s3api get-object \
            --region ${bucket_region} \
            --bucket ${bucket_name} --key leader_ipv4_local \
            leader_ipv4_local
ExecStart=/opt/bin/init-swarm.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When it runs, in an randomly and unexpected way at the first run I get the following error:

```
Dec 26 13:14:49 ip-192-168-4-70 docker[958]: Error response from daemon: Get https://quay.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Dec 26 13:14:49 ip-192-168-4-70 docker[965]: Unable to find image 'quay.io/coreos/awscli:latest' locally
Dec 26 13:15:04 ip-192-168-4-70 docker[965]: /run/torcx/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://quay.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
Dec 26 13:15:04 ip-192-168-4-70 docker[965]: See '/run/torcx/bin/docker run --help'.
```

When it runs for the second time then the pull succeed. Any idea?

Comment: What is the host information? Is it possible this is in a cloud environment where the networking is not up yet?

Comment: It runs on AWS.

Comment: @AndyShinn I've tried to create a dep with network-online.target by running the unit after it but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Seeing the same behavior. My unit file is even simpler. Just pulls an image and runs it on startup after docker.service. Logging in and manually running systemctl start works.